# couldn't begin new mongo() in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm beginner trying Mongodb.
I installed Mongodb and localhost:28017/ is working.
When I start service via terminal "/etc/init.d/mongodb start" it works.

But I added test.php file in /var/www/

```
<?php
$connection = new Mongo();
?>
```

but I'm getting server error "Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving localhost/test.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.".

Comment: That is the error? "server error"?

Comment: yes, it's "server error"

Comment: that's it 
"Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/test.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: does it work if you just `echo "Hello world"` without any mongodb?

Comment: @E_P yes it's working. I printed phpinfo().

Comment: Do you have php errors on as error you posted does not look like something from server

Comment: Have you installed the Mongo driver?

Comment: Mongo driver? Isn't having localhost:28017/ working meaning that mongodb driver working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5830260/984422

Comment: If you print phpinfo() do you see a section for `mongo`?

Comment: I solved it. I followed this tutorial  http://fv.cruxaustralis.net/languages/php/installing-mongodb-and-the-php-driver-in-ubuntu-10-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to MongoDB: the server part, and the client part. The server part does all the real work, but you need to be able to talk to it. Client libraries fill that gap. They abstract the underlying network communication and present a nice API (e.g., `new Mongo()`) to the user. You've got the server running; that's great. You have not, however, installed the client library for PHP, so PHP has no idea what to do with `new Mongo()`.

Comment: I solved it. I followed this tutorial http://fv.cruxaustralis.net/languages/php/installing-mongodb-and-the-php-driver-in-ubuntu-10-10/ . thanks for help